# swiping card in xamarin (visual studio) for android like google cards in maps/news

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, cardview

Below is my application layout and I've already included card view. But unable to make it swiping card like google cards in maps/news.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/contenLayout">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imgSource"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/image" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/content"
                    android:background="@color/orange"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need to load different data in each card swipe. Card swipes are reversible unlike simple touch event of screen.
Next card should be visible, when I'm swiping the card from left to right or right to left. I also checked for solution on xamarin forum and found xcardview which is only available for IOS.

Comment: Based on your description, are you asking for a horizontal `RecyclerView`? If not, can you please show a image to tell us what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Grace, But I found the solution on Xamarin Forum. Actually I was trying to achieve the functionality similar to ViewPager and Carousel View.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3174/viewpager-example-with-android-4-0

Below is the very nice sample by Cheesebaron on Git
https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on Xamarin Forum. Actually I was trying to achieve the functionality similar to ViewPager and Carousel View. Below is the link for discussion on ViewPager.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3174/viewpager-example-with-android-4-0

Below is the very nice sample code by Cheesebaron on Git
https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator